# Why are these ASCII methods inconsistent?

Tags: ascii, rust

When I look at the [rust ASCII operations](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/ascii.rs.html#13-877) it feels like there is a consistency issue between

is_lowercase/is_uppercase:

```
pub fn is_uppercase(&self) -> bool {
    (self.chr - b'A') < 26
}
```

is_alphabetic:

```
pub fn is_alphabetic(&self) -> bool {
    (self.chr >= 0x41 && self.chr <= 0x5A) || (self.chr >= 0x61 && self.chr <= 0x7A)
}
```

Is there a good reason? Are the two methods totally equivalent or am I missing something?
All these functions are marked as stable so I'm confused.

EDIT:

To make it clearer, what I would expect is to decide on the *best* (in terms of performance/readability/common practice) implementation for lower/upper then have

```
pub fn is_alphabetic(&self) -> bool {
    self.is_lowercase() || self.is_uppercase()
}
```

Comment: I don't know rust really, but I look at these definitions and they look "alright" to me - so perhaps you can explain more about *what* you think is inconsistent between them?

Comment: `is_uppercase` looks a bit problematic to me - ASCII NUL (or indeed anything less than `'A'`, wich includes the digits, most of the punctuation, and space) will be called "uppercase", unless rust only deals with unsigned numbers, and `x - y` is defined as `max(0, x - y)`... But I will admit to not knowing rust at all...

Comment: As Shepmaster mentioned, I think `x - y != max(0, x - y)`, because of unsigned math underflow. I too prefer `x >= b'a' || x <= b'z'` because it just look more generic than the 26 characters: if other character implementation use special characters like 'é' just after the 'e', then it would continue working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question changed to be about performance, I'll add a second answer.

To start, I created a clone of the Ascii module ([playpen](http://is.gd/LHLZgg)):

```
pub struct Alpha(u8);

impl Alpha {
    #[inline(never)]
    pub fn is_uppercase_sub(&self) -> bool {
        (self.0 - b'A') < 26
    }

    #[inline(never)]
    pub fn is_uppercase_range(&self) -> bool {
        self.0 >= 0x41 && self.0 <= 0x5A
    }
}

fn main() {
    let yes = Alpha(b'A');
    let no  = Alpha(b'a');

    println!("{}, {}", yes.is_uppercase_sub(), yes.is_uppercase_range());
}
```

In the playpen, make sure that the optimization is set to `-O2` and then click `IR`. This shows the LLVM **I**ntermediate **R**epresentation. It's like a higher-level assembly, if you'd like.

There's lots of output, but look for the sections with `fastcc`. I've removed various bits to make this code clearer, but you can see that the *exact same* function is called, even though our code calls two different implementations, one with a subtraction and one with a range:

```
%3 = call fastcc zeroext i1 @_ZN5Alpha16is_uppercase_sub20h63aa0b11479803f4laaE
%5 = call fastcc zeroext i1 @_ZN5Alpha16is_uppercase_sub20h63aa0b11479803f4laaE
```

The LLVM optimizer can tell that **these implementations are the same**, so really it's up to the developers preference. You might be able to get a commit into Rust to make them consistent, if you'd like! ^_^

Asking about `is_alphabetic` is harder; inlining will come into play here. *If* LLVM inlines `is_upper` and `is_lower` into `is_alphabetic`, then your suggested change would be better. *If* it doesn't, then potentially what was 1 function call is now **3**! That *could* be really bad.

These types of questions are a lot harder to answer at this level; one would have to do some looking (**edit** and profiling!) at real Rust code in the large to understand the optimizer with regards to inlining.

Comment: To optimize `is_alphabetic` I'd apply `input & ~0x20` to the input (converting it to upper case) and then check if it's an uppercase letter. At least with a dumb compiler that should be an improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the `IR` analysis. I won't of course get a commit for such a trivial change on Stable functions if there is no gain. The '3 calls' functions may be the true reason, but then, why is_alphabetic is used in is_alphanumeric ?

Comment: Well, Ascii is being [moved out of the standard library](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/5b115a291d7df256dd689e80b10c5da377855e3a/text/0486-std-ascii-reform.md), so you could [become a/the maintainer](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19908#issuecomment-67172743) if you'd like. ^_^

Comment: I really don't feel good enough for such task. But if I can help !

Answer (score 0):

They're equivalent. `is_alphabetic` could be written with byte literals instead of hex codes, making it more readable and matching the other functions:

```
pub fn is_alphabetic(&self) -> bool {
    (self.chr >= b'A' && self.chr <= b'Z') ||
    (self.chr >= b'a' && self.chr <= b'z')
}
```

Comment: Indeed byte literals are easier to read. I have edited my post to make my point clearer.

Comment: One fun about things like Rust: this may have just been written before byte literals were implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The values in `is_alphabetic` certainly correspond to the appropriate ASCII values for the letters. You can validate this with:

```
println!("0x{:x} 0x{:x}", b'A', b'A');
println!("0x{:x} 0x{:x}", b'a', b'z');
```

`is_alphabetic` relies on the fact that the ASCII lower and uppercase letters are sequential (not with each other, unfortunately). It could have been written:

```
pub fn is_alphabetic(&self) -> bool {
  (self.chr >= b'A' && self.chr <= b'Z') || (self.chr >= b'a' && self.chr <= b'z')
}

// Or
pub fn is_alphabetic(&self) -> bool {
  self.is_upper() || self.is_lower()
}
```

`is_lower` and `is_upper` both rely on unsigned math underflow to be correct. If `a` is `0x61` and `z` is `0x7A`, and we subtract `a` from both, we get `0` and `25`. However, if it's one less than `a`, we would get `0xFF`. `0xFF` is not `< 26`, so it will fail that check.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i edited my post to make it clearer. I am confused about having 2 different (even if conceptually equivalent) implementations. I don't know about llvm implementation but a substraction and a comparison just *look* different than 2 comparisons.

Comment: @tafia They're not all that different when you realize that the implementation of comparison of two integers in the vast majority of CPUs is simply subtracting the two numbers and throwing away the result, except for setting the flags...